# mingw g++ компиляция без консоли

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

Как можно скомпилировать c++ приложение в windows, чтобы оно запускалось без консоли? Я пробовал добавлять флаг -mwindows при компиляции, но тогда при запуске консоль на мгновение показывается и исчезает. Можно ли сделать как-нибудь, чтобы приложение без появляющийся на пару мгновений консоли в начале запускалось?

Comment: Ни разу не видел, чтобы с -mwindows появлялась консоль.

Comment: @mlkond, какая у Вас IDE?

Comment: Даниил, я не использую IDE, установил mingw отдельно и компилирую
g++ -c main.cpp -i a.o -Os -flto
g++ -o application.exe a.o -s -ffast-math -mwindows

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте параметр:  `-Wl,--subsystem,windows`.
Для проектов с OpenGL обычно помогает.

Comment: К сожалению и при компиляции с этими параметрами при запуске появляется консоль, которая тут же исчезает

Comment: тогда, может проблема в самом коде? я проверил с программой, которая активно пишет в stdout - нет окон... gcc 7.2 mingw-w64

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Ещё раз перепроверил, и обнаружилось, что при запуске вызывалась popen, которая создавала эту консоль.